# Team Foundation Server TFS 2015 Build Issue

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Can we demonstrate where the release number increase and stays in sequence when we use TFS (example 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc) and that when we do a build in Visual Studio the number in TFS will skip ahead by 1 (example – TFS build 1, 1.1, 1.2, build in Visual Studio, then do another build in TFS – the next number in TFS would be 1.4). This is for TFS 2015.

Comment: What question are you asking?

Comment: If I build from TFS or Visual studio the build number in TFS should been seen consistent. So if I build from TFS and the number is 1.1. Now I build from Visual Studio and just after that I build from TFS. So I want that build number to be 1.3 and not 1.2

Comment: Are you asking if that's the default behavior or how to implement that behavior? I'd say that it doesn't make sense to do that -- what if you have multiple people building locally? Their local versions will not be in sync.

Comment: I am asking how to implement that behavior if nobody is building locally and when everything is in Sync. In short behavior should be centralized.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the default increase mechanism in build number format. Unfortunately, it's impossible.`$(Rev:.rr)` Its start by one.

> **What is $(Rev:.rr)?**
>
> To ensure that every completed build has a unique name. When a build
>   is completed, if nothing else in the build number has changed, the Rev
>   integer value is incremented by one.
>
> Source:[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190719(v=vs.120).aspx#rev)

If you just want to override your Build number with variables, follow below steps:

1. Create a Powershell script like this:

   ```
    $FinalVersion=Some-Function-To-Calculate-Version
       $BuildDefName = $Env:BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME
       Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$($BuildDefName)-$($FinalVersion)"
   ```
2. In your vNext build definition, for "Build number format" you could set
   it to anything, cause the Build Number will be
   overwritten.
3. In the same vNext build definition steps, add the first step as a
   Powershell step, and set your script from step 1 to be executed. 
   You can later customize if you want to pass variables in order to
   calculate your build number.
4. Queue your build .

This is using the [logging commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) to set the build number.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question (as I understand it, at least). The question is around keeping TFS auto-incrementing build numbers and local build numbers within Visual Studio synchronized, which is weird (and I'd argue bad), but this answer certainly doesn't address that question.